# How to Report Income State Tax on Dividend Income from Mutual Funds While Traveling for an Extended Period

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax

I left Kansas in July 2022 and have not returned since. My income for the year 2022 is solely interest and dividend income from mutual funds, including emerging market and corporate funds. The sources of this income are not tied to any specific U.S. state.
I traveled several states during the period 7-2022 to 11-2022. I established residency in Ohio in December 2022.

How shall I report income state tax for the period 7-2022 to 11-2022?

Answer (score 2):

You generally report dividends in the state of residency, which would be Ohio and Kansas. If you were resident part year, you'll report dividends based on the dates received to the state where you were resident at the time.

You may be resident in multiple states at the same time, so you'll need to check the residency rules for each state, and their reciprocity conditions. Note that mere absence is not enough to not be a tax resident.